# Is there a way to remove the line under a symbol in Google map polyline?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-polyline

This link shows how to animate google map symbols: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-symbol-animate

Is there a way to remove the black line under the animated circle (but still show the green circle)?

Reason I am asking is because I want the animated circle to move ABOVE a dashed-line instead.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line is simply a Polyline object. Quickest solution is to hide it by setting the `strokeOpactity` to 0. Read more [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#polyline_add)

EDIT:
To make the symbol visible, you need to set its `strokeOpacity` to 1.0 to overwrite line's opacity. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/thovu/6hprmygo/1/) is a jsfiddle example.

Comment: I tried it but unfortunately it hides the CIRCLE element which I want to keep.
In the link on my question, I want to hide the black line, but still want to show the green circle.

Comment: Thanks! Will try this tomorrow. But it looks good to me already :)